# Iproute2 tools vs conntrack tools

Tags: iptables, tcpip, iproute2, conntrack

I have a linux box which is setup as firewall/gateway for the network. Was just wondering why ss and other iproute2 tools show much less than iptables conntrack. Is it because the router function is happening in kernel only?

```
ss -na
```

Shows only two established connections where as a

```
conntrack -L -n
```

Shows 18 Established connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ss` and `netstat` show connections terminated at that host, i.e. either outgoing connections created by a process on the host, or incoming connections handled by a process on the host. (Technically these show you sockets.) `conntrack` shows connections known by the connection tracking system, which includes connections being routed by but not terminated by that host. (Sockets don't exist for connections only being routed.)

Comment: Makes sense - is there another tool like ss that will show things like windows sizes etc of established sockets that do not have their endpoints on the box?

Comment: @AdrianCornish Not that I know of. Routers don't deal with that information so I doubt that it is recorded.

Comment: Shame really since this router has a full blown OS on it - but I guess windows sizes, keepalives etc is really more relevant at the endpoints - would be nice to it all at the gateway though.